# my websocket application won't work in my android

Tags: php, android, linux, websocket

I developed an application that works with the principles of chat using Ratchet. while it works normally in laptops, it won't work in my android. I used the chrome console and I got the error:

> ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Do you know how I could solve that error?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `Thank you in advance`? A good manner to chase people away. We do not want thank in advance.

Comment: well ok. thanks for the tip. english is not my native language. any help or are you just for my mistakes here?

Comment: You did not yet remove your mistake.

Comment: Do you know what `localhost` is?

Comment: @gre_gor yes I do. the localhost works fine for the web application in pc but not in the android. do you maybe have a solution to suggest?

Comment: @gre_gor ohhhh!!! I see your point! thank you for the tip